# Variable from Angular not passed to PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a problem where I am trying to pass a variable which was inputted by the `html` `form` -> passed through `angularJS` -> passed to `PHP`.The variables consists of: the `proverbDescription`, `proverbNumber` and the `imgPath` (path of the image).

When the image `submit` `button` is clicked, the image's path is uploaded in phpMyAdmin; however the proverbDescription and proverbNumber are not being uploaded. Instead I am receiving the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\php\addProverbs.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\php\addProverbs.php on line 7
```

What is possibly being wrong? I tried to change the variable to `$proverbDescription = $prov['proverbDescription'];` but unfortunately, nothing worked.

Below, kindly find the PHP code.

```
<?php
$prov = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
require_once("connection.php");

$connection = connectToMySQL();
$proverbDescription = $prov->proverbDescription;
$proverbNumber = $prov->proverbNumber;
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $target_dir = "../uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES['imageToUpload']['size'] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['imageToUpload']['name']). " has been uploaded.";
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_proverb (proverbDescription, proverbNumber, imgPath) VALUES ('$proverbDescription', '$proverbNumber', '$target_file')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
             or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
                $success = true;
        }else{
                $success = false;
        }
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}

?>
```

In case you need it, please find the `angularJS` `controller` here:

```
app.controller('proverbCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {  
    $scope.addProverb = function(prov) {
        $http.post('php/addProverbs.php', prov).success(function(prov) {
            console.log(prov);
        //  $location.path("/proverbs");
        });
    };
});
```

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($prov);die;`? Can you drop in on line 3 & share the output?

Comment: Hello @CameronHurd and thanks for your reply. The output is `NULL`. Although I still can't see how it's possible, I must be missing something :l 
Thanks!

Comment: Try `$http.post('php/addProverbs.php', {'prov': prov}).success(function(prov) {` and see if you get a non-null value!

Comment: Still `null` unfortunately :(

Comment: What about dumping the contents of `file_get_contents("php://input")` itself, before it hits `json_decode`?

Comment: how are you calling the addProverb function?